# Use Wordpress Text Editor in non-wp page

Tags: php

I have a page that is completely custom and does not fall into the Wordpress structure.  However it is using data from the WP database.  To access this I've used:

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('../wordpress/wp-load.php');
```

It using Blog Name and some other fields, plus some custom tables I've added to the DB)

I have verified that it is pulling info from the Wordpress DB correctly.

However I have a couple of textarea fields on this page that I'd like to be able to use the Wordpress WYSIWYG editor on them.

I've found posts on how to include it if you are writing a plugin, but other than the DB access this page isn't part of WP in any way.  Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!
Chris

Comment: These functions are available in the wordpress admin, I would assume that it's easier you code this on your own (wordpress uses [tinymce](http://www.tinymce.com/)) than reusing admin functions.

Answer (score 1):

Including `wp_load.php` performs WordPress core load and gives you access to normal (front-end) set of WordPress functions. You might need to include some files from admin area by hand to get access to functions from there. You will also need to call some WP hooks or deal with scripts manually.

Overall this is doable, but not trivial. Simply using TinyMCE directly may be more streamlined solution.